# Failed to send update request to backup node

Tags: gridgain

Gridgain version: 6.5.5
Cache mode: replaced
Cache K-V type: [Integer, Integer []]
Node startup mode: CMD ggstart -v -i
Problem description: When I'm start only one node, it can calculate correctly and the result is right, however, when I'm start multiple node with the example, it doesn't work and the exception information as follows.

```
SampleComputeNumTask.java:

    @Override
    public Collection<CbJob<Long, Integer[]>> splitJob(Serializable... args) throws CJobExcuteException {
        Collection<CbJob<Long, Integer[]>> list = new ArrayList<CbJob<Long, Integer[]>>();
        loadCache(args);
        GridCache<Integer, Integer[]> cache = grid.cache("share-hqfx");
        for (GridCacheEntry<Integer, Integer[]> entry : cache.entrySet()) {
            list.add(new CbJob<Long, Integer[]>(entry.getKey(), new MyCall(), entry.getValue()));
        }
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public void loadCache(Serializable... args) throws CJobExcuteException {
        GridCache<Integer, Integer[]> cache = grid.cache("share-hqfx");
        try {
            cache.globalClearAll(0);
        } catch (GridException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        int j = 0;
        int a = 0;
        int len = args == null ? 1000 : (Integer) args[0];
        Integer[] arg = new Integer[len];
        for (int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++) {
            arg[a] = i;
            a++;
            if (a == 1000 || i == 1000000) {
                ++j;
                try {
                    cache.putx(j, arg);
                } catch (GridException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                a = 0;
                arg = new Integer[1000];
            }
        }
    }
```

Exception trace:

```
[16:02:03,880][ERROR][gridgain-#60%rest-null%][GridDhtAtomicUpdateFuture] Failed to send update request to backup node (did node leave the grid?): 5e1b14d3-eb17-499d-9f0e-0de9a4a00c90
    class org.gridgain.grid.GridException: Failed to deploy class for local deployment [clsName=java.lang.Integer, ldr=GridUriDeploymentClassLoader [urls=[file:/F:/gridgain-fabric-ent/tmp/grid/gg.uri.deployment.tmp/41ed7058-4555-47d7-83e2-773436b2d12e/dirzip_SampleComputeTask5391357847454873740.gar/]]]
    For more information see:
        Troubleshooting:      http://bit.ly/GridGain-Troubleshooting
        Documentation Center: http://bit.ly/GridGain-Documentation

        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheDeploymentManager.registerClass(GridCacheDeploymentManager.java:624)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheDeploymentManager.registerClass(GridCacheDeploymentManager.java:562)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheMessage.prepareObject(GridCacheMessage.java:181)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheMessage.marshalCollection(GridCacheMessage.java:478)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicUpdateRequest.prepareMarshal(GridDhtAtomicUpdateRequest.java:576)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.onSend(GridCacheIoManager.java:334)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:362)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:350)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheIoManager.send(GridCacheIoManager.java:557)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicUpdateFuture.map(GridDhtAtomicUpdateFuture.java:324)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:1005)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsyncInternal(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:854)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicUpdateFuture.mapSingle(GridNearAtomicUpdateFuture.java:740)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicUpdateFuture.map0(GridNearAtomicUpdateFuture.java:581)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicUpdateFuture.mapOnTopology(GridNearAtomicUpdateFuture.java:454)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridNearAtomicUpdateFuture.map(GridNearAtomicUpdateFuture.java:319)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$13.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:662)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache$13.apply(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:660)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.asyncOp(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:584)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.updateAllAsync0(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:660)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.putxAsync(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:343)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheAdapter.putxAsync(GridCacheAdapter.java:2284)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.distributed.dht.atomic.GridDhtAtomicCache.putx(GridDhtAtomicCache.java:329)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.cache.GridCacheProxyImpl.putx(GridCacheProxyImpl.java:705)
        at com.topgether.cbgrid.datagrid.SampleComputeNumTask.loadCache(SampleComputeNumTask.java:64)
        at com.topgether.cbgrid.datagrid.SampleComputeNumTask.splitJob(SampleComputeNumTask.java:38)
        at com.topgether.cbgrid.datagrid.CGridTask.split(CGridTask.java:53)
        at com.topgether.cbgrid.datagrid.CGridTask.split(CGridTask.java:1)
        at org.gridgain.grid.compute.GridComputeTaskSplitAdapter.map(GridComputeTaskSplitAdapter.java:111)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$2.call(GridTaskWorker.java:404)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker$2.call(GridTaskWorker.java:402)
        at org.gridgain.grid.util.GridUtils.wrapThreadLoader(GridUtils.java:6078)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskWorker.body(GridTaskWorker.java:401)
        at org.gridgain.grid.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:151)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.startTask(GridTaskProcessor.java:607)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.task.GridTaskProcessor.execute(GridTaskProcessor.java:365)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.GridComputeImpl.execute(GridComputeImpl.java:122)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.rest.handlers.task.GridTaskCommandHandler.handleAsyncUnsafe(GridTaskCommandHandler.java:191)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.rest.handlers.task.GridTaskCommandHandler.handleAsync(GridTaskCommandHandler.java:138)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.handleRequest(GridRestProcessor.java:203)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor.access$100(GridRestProcessor.java:61)
        at org.gridgain.grid.kernal.processors.rest.GridRestProcessor$2.body(GridRestProcessor.java:109)
        at org.gridgain.grid.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:151)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Configuration:

```
<bean id="grid.cfg" class="org.gridgain.grid.GridConfiguration">
    <!-- Cache configurations. -->
    <property name="cacheConfiguration">
        <list>
            <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.cache.GridCacheConfiguration">
                <property name="name" value="share-hqfx" />
                <property name="cacheMode" value="REPLICATED" />
                <property name="queryIndexEnabled" value="true" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="restJettyPath" value="#{ systemEnvironment['GRIDGAIN_HOME'] }/config/jetty-config.xml" />

    <property name="deploymentSpi">
        <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.deployment.uri.GridUriDeploymentSpi">
            <property name="temporaryDirectoryPath" value="#{ systemEnvironment['GRIDGAIN_HOME'] }/tmp/grid" />
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="discoverySpi">
        <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.GridTcpDiscoverySpi">
            <property name="ipFinder">
                <bean class="org.gridgain.grid.spi.discovery.tcp.ipfinder.vm.GridTcpDiscoveryVmIpFinder">
                    <property name="addresses">
                        <list>
                            <!-- In distributed environment, replace with actual host IP address. -->
                            <value>127.0.0.1:47500..47509</value>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>

    <property name="deploymentMode" value="CONTINUOUS" />
</bean>
```

Comment: We tried to reproduce this issue for a week in different ways, but unsuccessfully. The weirdest thing is that `java.lang.Integer` is not properly loaded, which cannot be because it is a part of JDK. Could it be because you are putting JDK classes into your GAR file?

Comment: my github address is 'https://github.com/wwljy/gridcache'.you can rebuild my program.You have to use the command line mode(ggstart) to start multiple nodes, then post the url 'http://localhost:8090/gridgain?cmd=exe&async=true&name=SampleComputeNumTask&clientId=e67fce2c-8b22-4965-a87d-b91c3b6c65f7' then, this problem will reproduce.

Comment: hey, thank you for help me.By the way,I run it on old version (before 6.0.1), and it can run normal.

Comment: There were no changes in URI deployment between 6.0.1 and 6.5.5. I tried to reproduce this issue for a week in different ways, but unsuccessfully. The weirdest thing is that `java.lang.Integer` is not properly loaded, which should not happen because it is a part of JDK. Could it be because you are putting JDK classes into your GAR file?

Comment: I am sure that I didn't put the JDK class into the GAR file, I can work correctly on 5.1.2 version, but the version 6.0.1 and later versions can't run successfully.You can rebuild my project and get a new GAR file, the problem will be still exists.[link](https://github.com/wwljy/gridcache)

Comment: Is it possible to provide a reproducible code snippet with instructions how to reproduce? You can create a small project on GitHub or use any other file sharing or code sharing mechanism.